# How do I further progress?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have been playing terraria (on my iPad) a lot lately and I got full shadow armor and full nightmare tools, but I can't figure out what to do next... I already beat the eater of worlds like 4 times and harvested 3 meteors but I can't figure out what to do next... So what is the next big step in the world of terraria?

Edit: Ok so I got into hard mode but what do I do now? I decided to farm the wall of flesh a couple times but I can't really figure out how to progress more...

Comment: Also if I did something wrong in this question if you would tell me that would be great

Comment: Did you already ready these? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24950/what-is-the-progression-route-in-terraria?lq=1 http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203030/terraria-mobile-what-to-do-after-i-have-a-full-set-of-crimson-tools-armor http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141724/what-do-i-do-after-i-defeat-the-wall-of-flesh-in-the-mobile-edition-of-terraria?rq=1

Comment: Yeah I already saw those links  @Byte56

Comment: Thanks guys, so I did that what next?

Comment: @Drake so you've entered Hardmode as stated in the linked question? then i suggest you look at [the wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode) to see what is different now because i very much doubt that in 22 hours of having not known about Hardmode you have defeated every hardmode boss and gotten all new equipment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you follow MarioRPGGeno's answer, you must then fight the Demons in hell. When you fight them, there is a small chance that they will drop a Guide Voodoo Doll. At this point, you must throw the Voodoo Doll in the lava. (In the mobile version you just touch the vodoo doll on your hotbar) Upon performing this action, the Wall of Flesh will be summoned, and you will be dragged to its location by it's disgusting leechy-like claws. After you kill the Wall of Flesh, you will be in Hardmode! (Watch out for the box of items that it will spawn, these are very important)

- Make sure you drink all you potions, fighting the WoF is nothing like fighting other easymode bosses.
- Build a tunnel straight to hell, because if you die, the WoF will despawn if you don't get back down there quickly!
- Try fighting it with a friend. Friends are an important part of a lot of Terraria boss battles (Don't split any of the loot with them though XD )

Answer (score 1):

After you get shadow armor, you need to dig down to the Underworld, and harvest some Hellstone, but be careful as it drops lava when you mine it, and it's very dangerous in the Underworld as it's full of lava and monsters. :) EDIT: Just to clarify, the Underworld is the deepest layer, and it will take some time to mine to, or you can follow some caves down to it. I recommend to bring some Obsidian Skin potions. I believe they're crafted from Fireblossom, Obsidian, and a Water Bottle at an Alchemy Station. They will help you stay safe from the lava and prevent you from getting hurt by the Hellstone, it burns you even if you just step on it so you should stay to the ash. Btw, you will need Hellstone to craft Molten armor and the tool set. It won't be easy acquiring the needed Hellstone, and you will need a Hellforge which is found in the towers that generate in the Underworld to craft the Hellstone Bars which are then used to make the armor and tools at an anvil. It's the final tier of armor and tools before hardmode.

Comment: Why does he need to get Hellstone? Answers should be complete, not the start of a discussion.

Comment: Added the info about Hellstone :)

Comment: You're welcome :D I'm new to this site, so I was glad to help.